# How to find the spot where a block sliding in a curved surface stops?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A small block is let slide down a curved surface as indicated in the
>   picture from below. The curved surfaces have a negligible friction,
>   however the horizontal bottom which is of $12\,m$ in length is rugged.
>   The coefficient of kinetic friction of the bottom surface is $0.2$.
>   The block departs from rest $8\,m$ above the rugged bottom. Find the
>   position where the block stops.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{At 4m from B}\\
2.&\textrm{At 3m from C}\\
3.&\textrm{At 4m from C}\\
4.&\textrm{At 3m from B}\\
\end{array}$

This problem involves the use of conservation of mechanical energy. And the way how I attempted to solve it was:

$E_u=E_k$

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

$v^2=2gh$

Then It mentions that the coefficient of friction is 0.2, this means that when the block moves in the rugged surface the frictional force will be F=ma.

$f_s=F$

$ma=\mu N = \mu mg$

Then:

$a=\mu g$

From this I can find the distance using the equation:

$v_f^2=v_o^2-2a\Delta x$

Since it indicates that the body will finish at rest $v_f=0$

Therefore:

$\Delta x= \frac{v_o^2}{2a}$

Replacing the given values results as follows:

$\Delta x= \frac{2gh}{2(\mu g)}=\frac{h}{\mu}=\frac{8}{0.2}=40\,m$

But this length is way too long and exceeds the given length of the bottom. Did I made any sort of mistake?. Can somebody help me here?. Supposedly the answer is at $4\,m$ from $C$.

Upon thinking more deeply into it. I think that this means the cube will rise to the other end of the curved surface. But there isn't any specific indication that the curved surface is a quarter of a circle.

If I assume that the cube rise to the top and only gets to $D$ and slides down back:

I did calculated the speed after traveling $12\,m$

$v_f^2=16g-\frac{4\times 12}{10}g=\frac{56}{5}g$

But after that what distance will be taken into consideration?. The vertical?.

Assuming it it is the vertical until traveling

$B-C-D-C=12+8+8=28\,m$

Then I thought that it really doesn't matter this distance because those curved surfaces are of negligible friction so the same speed will be preserved at the bottom as the energy is conserved.

In the second travel from $C-B$:

$0=\frac{56}{5}g-2(\mu g)\Delta x$

$0=\frac{56}{5}g-2(0.2 \times g)\Delta x$

$x= 28\,m$

Again this exceeds the $12\,m$.

Then I must calculate again the final speed after $12\,m$.

$v_f^2=v_o^2-2a\Delta x$

$v_f^2=\frac{56}{5}g-\frac{4\times 12}{10}g=\frac{32g}{5}$

Then again calculating for a third travel from $BC$.

$v_f^2=v_o^2-2a\Delta x$

$0=\frac{32g}{5}-2(0.2 g )\Delta x$

$x=16\,m$

Again this exceeds the $12\,m$ limit.

Then I'm forced to calculate the speed for $12\,m$ after that fourth travel from $BC$.

$v_f^2=\frac{32g}{5}-2(0.2g\times 12)=\frac{8g}{5}$

Then finally from $CB$:

$0=v_o^2-2a\Delta x$

$0=\frac{8g}{5} - 2(0.2g)\Delta x$

$x=4\,m$

Which accounts for $4\,m$ from $C$ and it checks with the alternatives. And this corresponds to the right answer. But this procedure was too extense. Does it exist a reasonable shortcut?.

Comment: I've not gone through your solution with a fine-toothed comb, but I think your answer of 40 meters is consistent with the answer of 4 meters from C. If the block continues sliding the whole 12 meters, it will slide back up the other side, and then back down (and once it gets to the horizontal it should have the same velocity as when it left). Then it will go another 12 meters to the left, another 12 to the right, and finally 4 to the left since 12+12+12+4=40.

Comment: @kccu But for doing so you did not needed to follow up each segment with the speeds as I did. Why the computation which youdid works without considering the effect of the frictional decceleration for each segment?.

Comment: It does account for deceleration due to friction, but only when the block is on the flat portion. After the block slides up the right side and slides back down, it has the velocity as when it started sliding up (just opposite direction). So you can think of it as if the block has simply continued sliding on the flat surface.

Answer (score 2):

The block travels $40m$ on the flat portion. Since the two curved sections are frictionless, when the block reaches them at velocity $v$ it will go up to some height, stop, and return to the bottom with velocity $-v$. i.e. the slopes are there to make the problem *appear* more difficult to solve than it is. Then you count how many back-and-forths are needed to reach $40m$ total distance, which is B to C to B to C $+4$ more meters.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math symbols.